# Creating regex for function in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to create a regex to search SD-NNNNN (where N is a number) anywhere within an entry so that I can turn that into a hyperlink.

So you know what I'm trying to do, this is a simple Database entry that contains comments about something that has been done during the day, the comment may contain a ticket reference which is what I am trying to get so that it can then point to the URL of the ticket.

I can't seem to get my head around regex at all so I have no joy so far, not even sure if this is the right way to do things.

Here is my current code:

```
$cRow = current($row);
if ($cRow == "INSERT REGEX/PREG_MATCH/WHATEVER) {
    $regex = "<a href='http://something.com/search/$regex'>$regex</a>";
}

echo "<td style='word-wrap: break-word'>$cRow</td>";
next($row);
$y++;
```

Completely not finished yet but the basic idea is that $c_row could be anything but if it contains the SD-NNNNN then it would only replace the SD-NNNNN with a hyperlink whilst calling it the same thing.

Anybody able to help me with this?

Comment doesn't format code very well so here is the update:

This is what I tried:

```
$c_row = current($row);
$str = "<a href='https://example.com/browse/";
$regex = "/^SD-\d{5}/";
if (preg_match($regex, $c_row)
{
    $c_row = preg_replace($regex, $str$0, $c_row);
}
echo "<td style='word-wrap: break-word'>" . $c_row . '</td>';
next($row);
$y = $y + 1
```

Which gives me a 500 error for the { under the if.

Comment: `preg_match('/SD-\d{5}/', $str);` ?

Comment: Right now, the question is too unclear. Please provide more context. It is clear you want to match some `SD-xxxxx` text in some HTML. I suggest using a DOMDocument with DOMXPath to get text nodes, and do necessary replacements only inside them.

Comment: @stribizhev, question has been updated to show what I'm trying to do

Comment: Found the issue, missed a )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will match "SD-" and then five numbers:

```
$str = "SD-12345";
$regex = "/SD-\d{5}/"; ( put a caret ^ before, to match it in the beginning)
if (preg_match($regex, $str) {
    // do sth
}
// will match: SD-12345, will not match: SD-123456
```

If you want to replace it, you might want to use the following code:

```
$str = "SD-12345";
$regex = "/(SD-\d{5})/";
$replacement = "";
preg_replace($regex, $replacement, $str);
// will replace SD-12345 with ""
```

As @stribizhev pointed out, maybe you are trying to match HTML elements, for this purpose, a parser (e.g. SimpleXML) would be more suited anyway. The question remains somewhat vague.

Comment: It will match `SD-00000` in `OSD-00000000000000000000`.

Comment: Another potential bottleneck: the replacement is likely to take place in HTML code. Regex is not the best friend here, and with yours OP risks creating a node inside an attribute value.

Comment: @stribizhev: True as well :-)

Comment: @Jan - Thanks for that, It does need to be only SD-NNNNN though, also need to know how to only change the matched string as the rest of the string needs to stay intact.

PS - Sorry for not being clear

Comment: @PeteWall: You will need parentheses and `preg_replace()` then.

Comment: So you know what I'm trying to do, this is a simple Database entry that contains comments about something that has been done during the day, the comment may contain a ticket reference which is what I am trying to get so that it can then point to the URL of the ticket

Comment: This is what I tried:
`code`
    $c_row = current($row);
    $str = "<a href='https://example.com/browse/";
    $regex = "/^SD-\d{5}/";
    if (preg_match($regex, $c_row)
    {
        $c_row = preg_replace($regex, $str$0, $c_row);
    }
    echo "<td style='word-wrap: break-word'>" . $c_row . '</td>';
    next($row);
    $y = $y + 1

Comment: @Jan that's pretty much where I got to, have updated the question to show the code properly, getting a 500 error, can I not use $0?

Comment: @Jan, Thank you for your help!